# jqgrid - jumps to the end of the list in the select all records in edit

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid. it has 50 records. When I all records it goes to edit mode. Then the page jumps to the last row in the latest textbox. Is there a way so it stays on the first row. Maybe there is a way to give tabindex to each row's textbox. So it stays on the first row.
I also found [this](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/grid-scrolls-to-top-after-selecting-a-cell)
link. But it didn't fix the issue for me.

```
onSelectAll: function(aRowids, status) {
            if (status){
                for (var i = 0; i < aRowids.length; i++)
                    $('#ListTable').jqGrid('editRow',aRowids[i],true);

            } else {
                for (var i = 0; i < aRowids.length; i++) {
                    var tmp = getEditableCells('ListTable', aRowids[i]);
                    var record = composeEditedRecord(aRowids[i]);
                    updatedList[aRowids[i]] = record; //Put edited record into updatedList when unchecked
                    $('#ListTable').jqGrid('restoreRow',aRowids[i]);
                    $('#ListTable').jqGrid('setRowData',aRowids[i], tmp);
                }
            }
        },
```

Comment: @Kartikeya Khosla I posted the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the default behavior of the **jqGrid**. When a field is made editable and edit mode is turned on it highlights the field.

Probably you have already fixed the issue. But anyway , you can solve it with a simple trick. Just loop it in reverse order ,

```
 onSelectAll: function(aRowids) {
             for (var i = aRowids.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
                  $('#grid').jqGrid('editRow',aRowids[i],true);
        },
```

#### And , here is the [DEMO WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yNw3C/7958/)